# Python Tkinter and inheritance strange behaviour

Tags: python, tkinter, inheritance, init

I have a behaviour in python and Tkinter I do not understand.
I defined my own frame class and wanted to set certain options like a borderwidth and a relief, so that every frame I define uses theses settings.
I did

```
from Tkinter import *

class BaseFrame(Frame):
    def __init(self,master=None,cnf={}):
        Frame.__init__(self, master,cnf)
    
def main():
    root = Tk()
    
    f = BaseFrame(root)
    l1 = Label(f,text='test')
    l2 = Label(f,text='longtext')
    l1.pack()
    l2.pack()
    f.pack()
    root.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For now everything works a expected. Now I try to add settings to BaseFrame, so every frame is passed these settings.

I added to my **init** function:

```
self.configure(bg='red')
```

and got surprised, because this instruction seems to be ignored completely by the class.
if I add an option bg='red' to the creation call of f:

```
f = BaseFrame(root,bg='red')
```

it works.

```
Frame.configure(self,bg='red')
```

also doesn't work, as well as some other strange constructions. No matter what I try, I can only set settings on the creation of the object. Doing this form within the **init** function doesn't seem to work.

Now, how do I set options? Do I miss anything basic?

Comment: Are you setting your custom configuration before or after the call to the parent constructor (`Frame.__init__`)?  If you're not calling the parent constructor first, its most likely overwriting your configuration changes as the `Frame` initializes itself.

Comment: I call it after the call to the `Frame.__init__(self,master,cnf)`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the code in your question is your actual code, the `__init` function is never called, because it is called `__init` instead of `__init__`.  Every time you call `BaseFrame(stuff)` you are actually calling the super constructor, i.e. `Frame(stuff)`, because no specialized constructor is defined for `BaseFrame`.

Also, if you want to allow things like `BaseFrame(bg='red')` you have to change the last constructor argument to `**cnf` instead of `cnf={}`.

Comment: Thank you, Here is my updated code and it works as expected. Sorry for overseening the typo.

Comment: `from Tkinter import *

class BaseFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**cnf):
        default_cnf = {'bd':'1','relief':'raised'}
        default_cnf.update((k, v) for k, v in cnf.iteritems() if v is not '')
        Frame.__init__(self, master,cnf)
        
def main():
    root = Tk()
    
    f = BaseFrame(root)
    l1 = Label(f,text='test')
    l2 = Label(f,text='longtext')
    l1.pack()
    l2.pack()
    f.pack()
    root.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`
Presenting Code in comments is solved a little suboptimal.

Comment: To prevent overwriting my options:
`from Tkinter import *

class BaseFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**cnf):
        default_cnf = {'bd':'1','relief':'raised'}
        default_cnf.update((k, v) for k, v in cnf.iteritems() if v is not '')
        Frame.__init__(self, master,cnf)
        
def main():
    root = Tk()
    
    f = BaseFrame(root)
    l1 = Label(f,text='test')
    l2 = Label(f,text='longtext')
    l1.pack()
    l2.pack()
    f.pack()
    root.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`
Presenting code in comments is solved a little suboptimal.